# C - Use valgrind to detect memory leaks and context error in my criterion unit tests

Tags: c, valgrind, c-criterion

I'm trying to write unit tests for a C lib I've made.
To do so I'm using the lib `criterion`.

I would like to use valgrind to detect memory leaks and context error, when I run `make test` it generate a `unit_test.o` file that I can run throw valgrind and here is the result :

```bash
test: clean $(TEST_OBJ)
    $(CC) -o ${TEST_NAME} ${SRC} $(TEST_SRC) --coverage -lcriterion
    ./${TEST_NAME}
```

[image]

As you can see, I have 0 leaks and 0 context error which is not true as the tested code contains both. If I run the same code in the `main` function It will detect both leaks and contexts.

It looks like criterion execute the unit_tests in a kind of "safe" context and free all the memory itself.
My question is how can I test leaks and contexts from my criterion unit tests ?
Or, what are the alternative to test it ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with criterion, but I would hazard that it works by running tests in separate subprocesses / forks. Valgrind doesn't monitor subprocesses by default, but I think you can pass the `--trace-children=yes` to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to look at the documentation for Criterion — but the chances are high that the default mode launches tests in separate processes.

*[…Time passeth…]* The source code for the Snaipe/Criterion unit test framework is available on GitHub (at https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion), and one of the features claimed on the home page is "Test [sic] are isolated in their own process, crashes and signals can be reported and tested".

However, [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org) has options to help, notably:

- `--trace-children=no|yes`   Valgrind-ise child processes (follow execve)? [no].
- `--trace-children-skip=patt1,patt2,...`    specifies a list of executables that `--trace-children=yes` should not trace into.
- `--trace-children-skip-by-arg=patt1,patt2,...`   same as `--trace-children-skip=` but check the `argv[]` entries for children, rather than the exe name, to make a follow/no-follow decision.

Setting `--trace-children=yes` as an option to Valgrind should help you.

Comment: This is really interesting, still doesn't detect leaks but it works for context errors.
Probleme is that it never stop and I have to close my term to quit..
But this is a nice lead, thx

Comment: Fix the errors, it might finish correctly then.